# nhibernate: remove object from collection without deleting it

Tags: c#, nhibernate, collections

Let's say that we have a SPACE_SHIP and WEAPON objects. A SPACE_SHIP has one primary WEAPON and a collection of secondary WEAPON. I'd like to switch primary and one of the secondary WEAPON, how can I do that?

If I do:

1. mySpaceShip.SecondaryWeapons.Add(mySpaceShip.PrimaryWeapon)
2. mySpaceShip.PrimaryWeapon = theSecondaryWeaponToSwitch
3. mySpaceShip.SecondaryWeapons.Remove(theSecondaryWeaponToSwitch)

NHibernate error occurs... What shall I do?

Context: NHibernate 1.2, C# 3.5

Comment: If you are going to switch primary and sec weapons among themselves that means entities are interchangable and therefore you dont need two seperate entites like primary and seconday.you just need one weapon class which has a state which determines whether it is primary or not.

Comment: yes, we figured this out, but this is legacy code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most probably mapped it with `cascade="all-delete-orphan"`. When doing that, NH deletes all instances which had been removed from the collection. If you try to use that instance in another collection, NH complains.

NH doesn't implement "persistent garbage collection" to automatically detect which instances are referenced and which are not. This would be a much too strong performance impact. "delete-orphan" is a simplified version of that, which works in many simple cases, but doesn't work if you move instances around.

Comment: what should we do instead of `all-delete-orphan` ?

Comment: `cascade="all"` if you want to delete the elements when the parent is deleted (it shouldn't be in two collections at the same time). `cascade="none"` if the elements may be in more then one collection at the same time. In this case, you need to insert (`Safe`) and delete the elements separately in your code.